# Prevent links to be sent in HTML/PHP input forms

Tags: php, preg-match

I have the following input form in a html file

```
 <form action="contact.php" method="post" autocomplete="on">
                                <input type="text" name="Name">
                                <input type="text" name="Email">
                                <textarea name="Message"></textarea>
```

and the following contact.php file to send the message :

```
if (preg_match('(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*', $_POST['Message'])) {
// it's SPAM
die();
}

if(isset($_POST['Email'])){...
```

The result I'm looking for is to prevent links insertion in textarea.

If a link is inserted in the textarea, I still receive the email and I don't know what's wrong in my code.

Comment: `strip_tags` in the backend! Or the new PHP filters to control your input! If you only need to remove links then `preg_replace` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Probably not related to the problem, but `&amp;` should just be `&`. It looks like you copied that regexp from Javascript, which uses an HTML entity.

Comment: `preg_*` functions need delimiters. Probably an easier regex would be `~(?:ht|f)tps?)://\S+?\s~`.

Comment: Additionally have none of the answers on your previous questions resolved your issues? If they have please accept them.

Comment: What you describe matches URL, not links. Assuming this is what your objective, you need to be a bit more specific - is it ok for some to type a URL part (such as hostname + path) or do you need exclude anything which explicitly references content elsewhere on the internet? Are you trying to use the as a substitute for not escaping your output? (that would be bad)

Comment: if I change preg_match by     strip_tags the form dosent work anymore, if I change it for     preg_replace I still receive links in my emails.

Answer (score 0):

just find anchor tag by using regular expression or by xpath. it will easier and you can alert the user regarding the anchor tag and also you can make form disable for submitting the form.

regex:-

```
\<a.*(\s*)href+\=[\"\'].*[\"\'][.\s\w]*>[.\s\w\d]*\<\/a\>
```

xpath:-

```
var anchorCount = document.evaluate( 'count(//a)', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
alert( 'This document contains ' + anchorCount.numberValue + ' anchor elements' );
```